# Circular design pattern?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a class `A` and class `B`. Class `A` has a parameter which is a list of objects of class `B`. Class `B` has a parameter which is an object of instance `A`.

Would inheritance help me somehow here?

What would be the best design pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: "Would inheritance help me somehow here?" <- Help with what problem? I can't see any issue with the setup you describe; are you running into any problems in particular? (E.g., with type hints?)

Comment: you dont have to actually specify the type and treat everything as type "Object". circular dependencies are generally bad design however you turn them.

Comment: Right sorry. I get `Unresolved reference B`, so it seems I have to initialize the class B before class A. But when I do that I walk into the same problem with class A.

Comment: The solution is generally to break the circular dependency. Why do you have classes depending on each other like this?

Comment: I have an Image class and a subimage class. Image has to hold the list of subimages the image is made of, but each subimage class needs a paremeter that indicates which Image it belongs to.

Comment: It's a data dependency cycle, but it's not a problem. There are lots of mundane examples of such cycles: all adjacent nodes in a doubly linked list, for example, refer to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since no one replied so far, here's what I think.

- Circular reference is almost always the outcome of a bad design, so you should probably rethink the way your classes are defined. However, Python will happily accept it - your issue is probably with a type checker, or your IDE, not with Python
- Since you talked about inheritance: inheritance has nothing to do here, unless your `subimage` needs to inherit some methods/properties from `image`
- The usual way to represent a parent/children situation is to have the parent hold a list, dict, or whatever of its children. There should be no need for the children to reference their parent. In detail:

  - If a method works on one child only, it's a child method
  - If a method works on two children, it *may* still be a child method, with a signature like `do_something(self, other)`; or it may be a parent method with a signature like `do_something(self, child1, child2)`
  - If a method works with most or all the children, and/or the parent, then it definitely is a parent method
- If you're handling more than one `image` then you may want to define a three-level hierarchy: one singleton `catalog` object with a `self.images` properties; one `image` instance, with a `self.subimages` property, for each image (they will probably be identified by an ID of the form `iii`); and finally one `subimage` instance for each subimage (they will probably be identified by an ID of the form `iii_sss`)

```
class SubImage:
    def __init__(self, sub_ID):
        self.ID = sub_ID

class Image:
    def __init__(self, img_ID):
        self.ID = img_ID
        self.subimages = {}

    def add_subimage(self, sub_part_ID):
        sub_ID = f'{self.ID}_{sub_part_ID}'
        self.subimages[sub_ID] = SubImage(sub_ID)

class Catalog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.images = {}

    def add_image(self, img_ID):
        self.images[img_ID] = Image(img_ID)
```